# save a response from an api that returns csv file

Tags: python, api

I am developing a script that queries a REST API that returns a csv file, my problem is that I can not save this file locally on my machine.

Following my request API returns a non-encoded form (as shown in the attached picture)

PS :-  I develop my script in python

[image: 1]

i would like to have a solution to save csv file localy, on a specific path

Comment: Did you do any basic research? Show your code [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the binary REST API response to a file:

```py
from requests import get

resp = get("https://example.com/csv_api")

with open("test.csv", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

Comment: I tried, but the content saved in the file test.csv is in the form of weird characters, however when I try with postman api returns me the same form but when I use the option save as a file I have csv files that are saved in my local I tried, but the content saved in the file test.csv is in the form of weird characters, however when I try with postman api returns me the same form but when I use the option save as a file I have csv files that are saved in my local

Comment: @YoussefMouadden show us how the Postman request looks like, maybe there are certain headers sent/received that we should know?